# SSO flow with IS4

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect, idp

We have several web applications, all of which will be adapted to use a single authentication endpoint based on IdentityServer4 and OpenId Connect.

I would like some **argumented advice** regarding the following (simplified) flows that I'm considering.

1. **Cookies**:

   1. User accesses **app1** and hits *Login*
   2. User is taken to the IdP login page
   3. User logs-in and is taken back to **app1**
   4. **app1** provides a link to **app2**, which is clicked by the user
   5. **app2** takes her to the IdP login page
   6. IdP **cookies** haven't expired, and therefore, no user credentials are requested. Consequently, the user is auto-logged-in and taken back to the **app2**.
2. **Token**-based authentication:

   1. User accesses **app1** and hits *Login*
   2. User is taken to the IdP login page
   3. User logs-in and is taken back to **app1**
   4. **app1** provides a link to **app2**, which is clicked by the user
   5. **app1** redirects the user to **app2** but also provides the *id_token* obtained previously from the IdP (item 2.3 above)
   6. **app2** verifies that the *id_token* is valid and automatically logs the user in.

Questions:

1. Which one is better? (Cookies vs. Token "sharing")
2. Is there a different (i.e. better) flow I should implement?

Comment: Do you have sample for implementing Token-base Authentication as you have mentioned above. I want to learn it.

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. We ended up going with option 1, which comes out of the box with IS4.

Answer (score 1):

Flow #2 is preferred, and here's why I believe so:

The critical item in flow #1 is step 1.6 where **app1**'s cookies are evaluated for expiration. the key here (in my opinion) is that cookies should be app-specific and **app1**'s cookies should not be tested when **app2**'s user is authenticated.

Conversely in flow #2, step 2.6 should be performed by **app1** (as the referrer) so **app1** and the identity provider agree that the authentication token is still valid and **app2** can proceed using **app1** as a deferred authenticating application.

IdP can legitimately validate (or refresh for that matter) a token from any application, whereas a cookie should be managed as application- (or session-) specific.

**A 3rd more ideal method:**
Each app should have **its own authentication context from IdP** and when **app1** authenticates, each of the linked applications can authenticate as well with the same user credentials. In this pattern, applications can expire tokens at different times (for example: viewing 2 hours, but editing only 30 minutes.)
The key to this approach is that SSO credentials are accessed once, authenticated for all the application contexts, and token lifetimes are managed on a per-app basis from then on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Small note: in step 1.6 above, it is the IdP the one that verifies that the idp-domain cookies (provided by the browser) haven't expired, and avoids asking the user to provide their credentials again. Therefore, no web app is trying to inspect other web app's cookies.

Regarding the ideal method, are you referring to a pattern such as AZA, in which an Authorization Agent (although, it would be an Authentication Agent) is put in front of all applications to handle SSO?

Comment: You did a good job of clarifying the IdP-domain cookies, and Yes AZA is in summary the pattern I described, although AZA describes an agent just for AAA purposes...your first app1 could take on AZA responsibility if you always enter there, or more flexibly,  any app could inherit from an AZA interface set, then any entry point becomes the AZA .

Comment: I don't agree re flow 2. A client app can only validate an id_token issued to it directly. Flow #2 is not a standard flow and #1 is the correct approach as long as we're all in agreement that it's the IDP's auth cookie that allows for seemless SSO.

Comment: The IdP cookies are indeed the ones that allow for seemless SSO